# Java find the largest attribute between different objects of the same class

Tags: java, object-comparison

I'm trying to find which warehouse has the greatest number of each part. I set up a super class defined below.

```
 public abstract class warehouse {
    int part1;
    int part2;
    int part3;
    int part4;
    int part5;
    String name;
    File inventory = new File("Inventory.txt");
    File transactions = new File("Transactions.txt");
    public warehouse() throws FileNotFoundException {

    }

    public int getPart1() {
        return part1;
    }
    public int getPart2(){
        return part2;
    }
    public int getPart3() {
        return part3;
    }
    public int getPart4() {
        return part4;
    }
    public int getPart5() {
        return part5;
    }
```

I have six subclasses, I'll show the definition of one, they're all the same except for the name field.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Atlanta extends warehouse {

    public Atlanta() throws FileNotFoundException {
        name = "Atlanta";
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare for example, `part1` between all six classes. I set up the functions to return the values of each of the parts but it would really suck to do if `(Atlanta.getPart1() > Chicago.getPart1() && Atlanta.getPart1()> Denver.getPart1())...` is there a way I can find which object has the greatest value of each attributes without having to write that out for every combination and every part?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why a subclass for each location? Why not just a different instance of warehouse and some sort of collection class to hold all your warehouses. Then the collection class can have a method to tell you which warehouse has the most "part 4s" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)) with proper `Comparator` based on abstract class

```java
Collections.max(
  Arrays.asList(new Atlanta(), new Pennsylvania(), ...),
  Comparator.comparing(warehouse::getPart1)
);
```